# Grafana on azure app service does't find Log analytics workspace

Tags: grafana, azure-monitor, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I deployed Grafana on azure app service, i want to connect it to azure monitor,
1- i registered the app in azure AD
2- i granted api permission to my add (log analytics reader)
3- i granted reader role at subscription level resource group, and workspace

when i hit the save& test button i get the following:

1. Successfully connected to azure monitor endpoint
2. No log analytics workspace found
3. error connecting to azure Resource Graph endpoint: {"error"{"code":"BadReques","message" ...............timestamp and corelationId
   "code": subscriptionContainsInvalidGuids:

Please note that in azure monitor data source i can't find my subscription my i hit the load button it doesn't show any subscription.

i tried to connect grafana to azure monitor and i was expecting the connexion to work and i would be able to query azure metrics and logs

Answer (score 0):

I switched to managed identity and it worked, it seems that deploying grafana from docker hub into azure app service doesn't give much flexibility for config, so i had to create my custom grafana image and push it to azure container registry

after that i switched from azure ad service principle authentication to managed identity and it worked.